# Did the events of LOTR War in the North take place in Tolkien’s writings?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

I played [LOTR War in the North](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings%3a_War_in_the_North) and I wonder if the characters from the game were really mentioned by Tolkien.

Did this war really take place in parallel with adventure of the Fellowship? Who are Agandaur and Ugost? What locations were depicted as they really are in Middle-Earth?

Comment: “as they really are in Middle-Earth” — you weren’t one of those kids who [thought that the Battle of Helm’s Deep actually happened](http://www.theguardian.com/education/2004/aug/05/schools.highereducation), were you?

Comment: I mean relatively to Arda :)

Comment: Some people believe in God. Can you really say sure that no Maiar walked among us?

Comment: @Trollwut: some people believe that an invisible hamster controls whether people have good hair days. That doesn’t make it real.

Comment: Thou shall beware the day of the hamster/tentacle!

Comment: @Simon - Letter 144: "Dragons. They had not stopped; since they were active in far later times, close to our own. Have I said anything to suggest the final ending of dragons? If so it should be altered. The only passage I can think of is Vol. I p. 70 : 'there is not now any dragon left on earth in
which the old fire is hot enough'. But that implies, I think, that there are still dragons, if not of full primeval stature."

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - tons of modern youth think that [living in socialism is a lot better than capitalism](http://occupywallst.org/). I don't consider those who think Middle-Earth is real thing to be nearly as deluded.

Comment: @DVK: Then you’re pretty certain about the relative benefits of living in socialism and capitalism.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - having actually lived in socialism, it makes me eminently more qualified to discourse on the comparison vs. those privileged iPhone toting dolts.

Comment: @DVK: fair play.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer - I'm not personally familiar with this game.

These characters (based on info at the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings%3a_War_in_the_North#Characters)) don't exist in Tolkien's writings - they're inventions of the game.

Tolkien's writings however **do** cover events of a northern (relative to the main action in Gondor and Mordor) extension of the War of the Ring, with several other battles occurring "off-camera".  These are best summarized in Return of the King Appendix B: the Tale of Years; I'll list the major such conflicts here and refer you to that source for further info:

- First Battle of the Fords of Isen
- Second Battle of the Fords of Isen
- Invasion of Eastern Rohan
- First Assault on Lórien
- Battle of Mirkwood
- Second Assault on Lórien
- Battle of Dale and Siege of Erebor
- Third Assault on Lórien
- Destruction of Dol Guldur

Of the locations at the same Wikipedia article, Nordinbad and Urgost Lair are non-Tolkien (inventions of the game), but everything else is in Tolkien, although some of it may be scattered across multiple different sources (some not in wide circulation).  Note however that under the terms of the Middle-earth Enterprises License, only material from the Hobbit and Lord of the Rings may be legally used, and so any information about a location that comes from other sources should not be present here.

Since so much important information is collected in Unfinished Tales, the History of Middle-earth, and essays published in periodicals (such as the Rivers and Beacon-hills of Gondor essay - a key source) it's therefore impossible for any licensed work to depict many locations how they really are in Middle-earth - licensed works are just not legally allowed to use that information.